# Sending E-mail to multiple people using input type "submit" whose E-mail address is in an HTML table

Tags: html, forms, email, html-table

I have an HTML table with 3 columns of E-mail addresses.  I am trying to figure out how I would go about sending out a mass E-mail to all the E-mail addresses that are in the table using the form action=mailto: and assigning that action to an input type="submit" button.  Basically what I'm looking for is when I press the submit button, the browser will open my E-mail client and include everyone's E-mail address in it.  I would imagine I have to assign some sort of ID to everyone's email address so when I press the button, the form will scan the table for an E-mail address to include in the "to" block of an E-mail.

Here is an example:

```
<form action="mailto:?"method="get">
<table class="rep">
<th class="rep">Office</th>
<th class="rep">Primary Representative</th>
<th class="rep">Alternate Representative</th>
<th class="rep">Phone #</th>
<th class="rep">Pri. E-mail</th>
<th class="rep">Alt. E-mail</th>
<th class="rep">Supervisor</th>
<th class="rep">Sup. E-mail</th>

<tr class="rep">
    <td class="rep">Mail Room</td>
    <td class="rep">Harry Frill</td>
    <td class="rep">Jack Daniels</td>
    <td class="rep">123-456-7890</td>
    <td class="rep"><a href="mailto:HarryF@yahoo.com">E-Mail</td>
    <td class="rep"><a href="mailto:JDaniels@yahoo.com">E-Mail</td>
    <td class="rep">Lauren Jory</td>
    <td class="rep"><a href="mailto:LaurenJ@yahoo.com">E-Mail</td>
</tr>   
    <tr class="rep">
    <td class="rep">Labs</td>
    <td class="rep">Jay Holiday</td>
    <td class="rep">Tony Tarks</td>
    <td class="rep">987-676-5432</td>
    <td class="rep"><a href="mailto:Jholiday@yahoo.com">E-Mail</td>
    <td class="rep"><a href="mailto:TTarks@yahoo.com">E-Mail</td>
    <td class="rep">Ben Dinkle</td>
    <td class="rep"><a href="mailto:BDinkle@yahoo.com">E-Mail</td>
</tr>   
<input type="Submit" value="E-Mail all reps">
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: That's not how `"action="mailto:"` works. What do you mean by "generate an e-mail"? Do you mean the *server* will email everybody (in which case you will need to write your code in something like PHP)? Or will the *client* (browser) open an email ("mailto:") link with the "to" address being a comma-separated list of the email addresses (in which case you can do this with Javascript)? You need to be more specific. And please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73596778/edit) to show us this mysterious HTML table.

Comment: Where is the submit button?

Comment: Edited to include the table and clarification on how the E-mail will be generated.  If this isn't a function that a form action can handle, then maybe I will have to look into using Javascript.  Thanks for the advise.

Comment: The email addresses as shown are in `<a>` tags, which don't get submitted to the server when you submit the form. You also didn't include a `<form>` tag. So you will have to use Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a button, along with an event listener that, when clicked, runs through all the `<a>` tags, extracts their email address, and creates a `mailto:` URL that includes all those addresses, and redirects the user to that URL.

```js
document.querySelector('button#doIt').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var emails = []
    document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="mailto:"]').forEach(function(elmt){
        var email = elmt.getAttribute('href').replace(/^mailto:/, '')
        emails.push(email)
    });
    document.location.href = 'mailto:' + emails.join(',')
});
```

```html
<table class="rep">
<tr>
    <th class="rep">Office</th>
    <th class="rep">Primary Representative</th>
    <th class="rep">Alternate Representative</th>
    <th class="rep">Phone #</th>
    <th class="rep">Pri. E-mail</th>
    <th class="rep">Alt. E-mail</th>
    <th class="rep">Supervisor</th>
    <th class="rep">Sup. E-mail</th>
</tr>
<tr class="rep">
    <td class="rep">Mail Room</td>
    <td class="rep">Harry Frill</td>
    <td class="rep">Jack Daniels</td>
    <td class="rep">123-456-7890</td>
    <td class="rep"><a href="mailto:HarryF@example.com">E-Mail</td>
    <td class="rep"><a href="mailto:JDaniels@example.com">E-Mail</td>
    <td class="rep">Lauren Jory</td>
    <td class="rep"><a href="mailto:LaurenJ@example.com">E-Mail</td>
</tr>   
<tr class="rep">
    <td class="rep">Labs</td>
    <td class="rep">Jay Holiday</td>
    <td class="rep">Tony Tarks</td>
    <td class="rep">987-676-5432</td>
    <td class="rep"><a href="mailto:Jholiday@example.com">E-Mail</td>
    <td class="rep"><a href="mailto:TTarks@example.com">E-Mail</td>
    <td class="rep">Ben Dinkle</td>
    <td class="rep"><a href="mailto:BDinkle@example.com">E-Mail</td>
</tr> 
</table>
<button id="doIt">Do it!</button>
```